# strftime function in SQLite does not work

Tags: sqlite, strftime

Hi, I am using the following query but it does not work,

```
SELECT strftime('%m',Since) AS Month FROM Dates
```

Type of `Since` column is `DATETIME`, but the result is shown an empty Month column without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) isn't broken, it just doesn't understand the format of the datestamps in your database.

```
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
sqlite> create table dates (id int, d datetime);
sqlite> insert into dates (id,d) values (1, date('now'));
sqlite> insert into dates (id,d) values (2, 'bad date');
sqlite> insert into dates (id,d) values (3, NULL);
sqlite> insert into dates (id,d) values (4, datetime('now'));
sqlite> select * from dates;
1|2012-09-23
2|bad date
3|
4|2012-09-23 04:31:36
sqlite> select id, strftime('%m', d) from dates;
1|09
2|
3|
4|09
```

Comment: how to fix this ? i.e time stamp VARCHAR(16) for example : 2017-05-02040402

Comment: SQLite date are stored as epoch in milliseconds, but strftime get seconds. so you have to divid your date by 1000: `SELECT strftime('%m',Since/1000) AS Month FROM Dates`