# How to format DateTime column in query for sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I want my datetime table column in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format

I am using

```
SELECT AIRPORT_NAME , strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 'CREATETS')as crts FROM AIRPORT_MASTER where AIRPORT_MASTER_ID = 1;
```

**CREATETS** is my datetime column having data in "21-03-2011 12:00:00.000000" format

This as query but doesn't work fine in my case, sqlite don't show any error but no output in this case 
help me to get

"2011-03-21 08:55:36" as output format

Comment: You can get date from db in any format(Simply as string) then convert it different date format in android..

Comment: but can't i get in query itself?..so tht i can save my code lines

Comment: @AditiK Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832864/compare-dates-stored-as-string-in-android-sqlite-database

Comment: @PankajKumar i am not storing my date in string format ..its in DateTime format of Sqlite

Comment: Are you sure you get it fine if you retrieve it as a `String` ? In other word, are you sure this is only a problem with the format you're retrieving it in ?

Comment: @AditiK Really? SQLite supports DateTime data type? I didn't know.

Comment: @pankaj I am confused whether it is ryt or wrong but i got one link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549671/strftime-function-in-sqlite-does-not-work

Comment: @AditiK Don't be confused.. That is for normal SQLite. Not for the SQLite which supported by Android. See laaltoo's answer. Better, go with his last paragraph :)

Comment: cm to chat don't post here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `'CREATETS'` is a string literal and not a column name. If you need to refer to a column, remove the `''` quotes.

Second, `21-03-2011 12:00:00.000000` is not a [time string as understood by sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and attempting to convert it using datetime functions will result in null.

Technically it is possible to convert the your datetime values to a time string understood by sqlite using `SUBSTR()` to extract parts of the value and reorder the fields.

However, SQL is not the right place to put your presentation/formatting code in. Do that in your Java code instead. Also, it would be easier if you just stored timestamps in a "raw" format such as unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) or Java milliseconds timestamp instead of formatted strings.

Comment: When you store raw timestamps, you will also need to store timezones in another column. Thus a common timezone aware dateformat is easier.